# Automatically Download PDF Links to Desktop Folder

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have code that loops through a list of hyperlinks in Excel and batch downloads these links as PDFs.

Sometimes they save to my desktop, documents, or another file path.

I would like them saved to a designated folder on my desktop named "PDFs."

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile _
  Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
  (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
  ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Function DownloadFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean
Dim lngRetVal As Long
lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0)
If lngRetVal = 0 Then DownloadFile = True
End Function

Sub DownloadPDFs()

Dim StartRowNum As Long
Dim EndRowNum As Long
Dim pdfname As String
Dim RecordNum As String
Dim URLprefix As String

LastRowPDF = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRowPDF

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    URLprefix = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
    RecordNum = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
    pdfname = RecordNum & ".pdf"

    URL = URLprefix

    DownloadFile URLprefix, pdfname
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Next i

End Sub
```

How do I save to a specific folder path?

Comment: `pdfname = "C:\ThisIs\ThePath\" & RecordNum & ".pdf"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the method I use and it works well, especially if you may need to use the file on multiple computers where the user profile may change, for example sending to others to execute the print operation or printing from another desktop. This method does not set a static path specific to your PC, but rather a path according to the PC it is being run on.  A more flexible solution.

```
'Set Filename
pdfname = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\PDFs\" & RecordNum & ".pdf"
```